# How can we derive the third term of a quadratic approximation for a quadratic function?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I am OK deriving the linear approximation for a typical quadratic function  and also the quadratic approximation for this same function. Using the quadratic approximation we can find the functions coefficients.

But this is still an approximation.    Assuming this approximation can be made more accurate how do we derive it?  The coefficients are already known from the quadratic approximation.

Comment: If the original function is quadratic, then the "quadratic approximation" will in fact be identically equal to the original function, and not actually "approximate" at all.

Comment: ...so if the approximation formula is the same as the power of the function to be approximated then the solution is exact ?    I am trying to figure out what "higher order terms" in the calculus of variations method of finding the solution to a stationary action of the Lagrangian.  I don't see no "higher terms" ...I just see a second power when the variation in path is squared...so I thought I would start from the ground up with understanding approximations

Comment: Yes, it amounts to just rewriting the function in another form.  For example if you "approximate" $f(x) = x^2$ around $x_0=1$ you get $f(x) = (x-1)^2 + 2(x-1) + 1$, but if you expand the latter formula and simplify you will see it is exactly the same as the original one.

Comment: do you mind doing that with a cubic ....I am curious .....I am sure there is a theorem for this ....perhaps this is the motivation for the Taylor expansion ..?